# How do I slide in / fade in text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble getting my list of sentences slide and fade into one another.

- This is what i've got: http://mailninja.co.uk/ifttt.html (see source
  for complete code)
- This is what i want to achieve: https://www.mailerloop.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could have solved this with a minimum effort of yourself, like typing this into google.

Comment: _"see source for complete code"_ - And what did you discover when you checked the source of the page you're trying to emulate?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any fade in/out feature in your code.
You can lear needed part of jQuery ( http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ )
OR... just copy the expected code (that use jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery effects. Take a look at the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). jQuery has alot of slide in slide out, fade and many many more effects.